# Frame/table in Android activity?

Tags: android

I`m beginner at Java coding and would like to use ad advice. Sorry for basic question, butu I couldn`t find what I was looking for.

I would like to read SqLite database and present its data in mainactivity.
Below is an example how it should look (in example there are two rows presented - 1 and 2).

[activity example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJUV0.png)

Question is which method/class should I use to create frames (1 and 2 in example) that would be automatically updated basing on the number of rows in SqLite.
It means that if SqLite has 5 rows, I would like to have 5 frames which would present data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use android `ListView`or `RecyclerView` with your Custom adapter or you could use default adapter for `ListView`.

Read more about `ListView` and `RecyclerView`.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: An adapter based view might be overkill, as there is no requirement stated for scrolling or view recycling

Comment: thanks. scrolling would be an asset.

another questions. is it possible to make a specific cell clickable in RecyclerView or only whole row would be clickable ?

Comment: @RobCo According to the question, developer is not sure about the content size. So I believe recycle view will not overkill. It will be a saver .

Comment: @Michal you can make individual item of row clickable or complete. Its upto your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridView or RecyclerView and set the data using adapter.

So that when you have 5 rows. It will set data into 5 rows. And additionally GridView or Recycler view will give you smooth scrolling effact.

Answer (score 0):

Here sharing an example. DBManager is an Interface you can use to add, delete, update rows. And MainActivity shows its usage.

```
package in.apachetechnology.apachedb;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBManager
{
    // the Activity or Application that is creating an object from this class.
    Context m_oContext;

    // a reference to the database used by this application/object
    private SQLiteDatabase m_sqlDB;

    // These constants are specific to the database.  They should be 
    // changed to suit your needs.
    private final String cDB_NAME = "database_name";
    private final int cDB_VERSION = 1;

    // These constants are specific to the database table.  They should be
    // changed to suit your needs.
    private final String cTABLE_NAME = "database_table";
    private final String cROW_NAME_ID = "id";
    private final String cROW_NAME_ONE = "table_row_one";
    private final String cROW_NAME_TWO = "table_row_two";

    public DBManager(Context c)
    {
        m_oContext = c;

        // create or open the database
        CustomSQLiteOpenHelper helper = new CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(c);
        m_sqlDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    /**********************************************************************
     * ADDING A ROW TO THE DATABASE TABLE
     * 
     * This is an example of how to add a row to a database table
     * using this class.  You should edit this method to suit your
     * needs.
     * 
     * the key is automatically assigned by the database
     * @param rowStringOne the value for the row's first column
     * @param rowStringTwo the value for the row's second column 
     */
    public void addRow(String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo)
    {
        // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite     functions
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(cROW_NAME_ONE, rowStringOne);
        values.put(cROW_NAME_TWO, rowStringTwo);

        // ask the database object to insert the new data 
        try{
            m_sqlDB.insert(cTABLE_NAME, null, values);}
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**********************************************************************
     * DELETING A ROW FROM THE DATABASE TABLE
     * 
     * This is an example of how to delete a row from a database table
     * using this class. In most cases, this method probably does
     * not need to be rewritten.
     * 
     * @param rowID the SQLite database identifier for the row to delete.
     */
    public void deleteRow(long rowID)
    {
        // ask the database manager to delete the row of given id
        try {
        m_sqlDB.delete(cTABLE_NAME, cROW_NAME_ID + "=" + rowID, null);}
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**********************************************************************
     * UPDATING A ROW IN THE DATABASE TABLE
     * 
     * This is an example of how to update a row in the database table
     * using this class.  You should edit this method to suit your needs.
     * 
     * @param rowID the SQLite database identifier for the row to update.
     * @param rowStringOne the new value for the row's first column
     * @param rowStringTwo the new value for the row's second column 
     */ 
    public void updateRow(long rowID, String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo)
    {
        // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(cROW_NAME_ONE, rowStringOne);
        values.put(cROW_NAME_TWO, rowStringTwo);

        // ask the database object to update the database row of given rowID
        try {
            m_sqlDB.update(cTABLE_NAME, values, cROW_NAME_ID + "=" + rowID, null);}
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**********************************************************************
     * RETRIEVING A ROW FROM THE DATABASE TABLE
     * 
     * This is an example of how to retrieve a row from a database table
     * using this class.  You should edit this method to suit your needs.
     * 
     * @param rowID the id of the row to retrieve
     * @return an array containing the data from the row
     */
    public ArrayList<Object> getRowAsArray(long rowID)
    {
        // create an array list to store data from the database row.
        // I would recommend creating a JavaBean compliant object 
        // to store this data instead.  That way you can ensure
        // data types are correct.
        ArrayList<Object> rowArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
        Cursor cursor;

        try
        {
            // this is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
            // the cursor object store the information collected from the
            // database and is used to iterate through the data.
            cursor = m_sqlDB.query(
                cTABLE_NAME,
                new String[] { cROW_NAME_ID, cROW_NAME_ONE, cROW_NAME_TWO },
                cROW_NAME_ID + "=" + rowID,
                null, null, null, null, null
            );

            // move the pointer to position zero in the cursor.
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // if there is data available after the cursor's pointer, add
            // it to the ArrayList that will be returned by the method.
            if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                do {
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(2));
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // let java know that you are through with the cursor.
            cursor.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)  {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return the ArrayList containing the given row from the database.
        return rowArray;
    }

    /**********************************************************************
     * RETRIEVING ALL ROWS FROM THE DATABASE TABLE
     * 
     * This is an example of how to retrieve all data from a database
     * table using this class.  You should edit this method to suit your
     * needs.
     * 
     * the key is automatically assigned by the database
     */

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getAllRowsAsArrays()
    {
        // create an ArrayList that will hold all of the data collected from
        // the database.
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

        // this is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
        // the cursor object store the information collected from the
        // database and is used to iterate through the data.
        Cursor cursor;

        try {
            // ask the database object to create the cursor.
            cursor = m_sqlDB.query(
                cTABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{cROW_NAME_ID, cROW_NAME_ONE, cROW_NAME_TWO},
                null, null, null, null, null
            );

            // move the cursor's pointer to position zero.
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // if there is data after the current cursor position, add it
            // to the ArrayList.
            if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                do {
                    ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                    dataList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(2));

                    dataArrays.add(dataList);
                }
                // move the cursor's pointer up one position.
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return the ArrayList that holds the data collected from
        // the database.
        return dataArrays;
    }

    /**
     * This class is designed to check if there is a database that currently
     * exists for the given program.  If the database does not exist, it     creates
     * one.  After the class ensures that the database exists, this class
     * will open the database for use.  Most of this functionality will be
     * handled by the SQLiteOpenHelper parent class.  The purpose of extending
     * this class is to tell the class how to create (or update) the database.
     */
    private class CustomSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(Context m_oContext)
        {
            super(m_oContext, cDB_NAME, null, cDB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase m_sqlDB)
        {
            // This string is used to create the database.  It should
            // be changed to suit your needs.
            String newTableQueryString = "create table " +
                                    cTABLE_NAME +
                                    " (" +
                                    cROW_NAME_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
                                    cROW_NAME_ONE + " text," +
                                    cROW_NAME_TWO + " text" +
                                    ");";
            // execute the query string to the database.
            m_sqlDB.execSQL(newTableQueryString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase m_sqlDB, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            // NOTHING TO DO HERE. THIS IS THE ORIGINAL DATABASE VERSION.
            // OTHERWISE, YOU WOULD SPECIFIY HOW TO UPGRADE THE DATABASE.
        }
     }
 }
```

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // the text fields that users input new data into
    EditText textFieldOne, textFieldTwo,
            idField,
            updateIDField, updateTextFieldOne, updateTextFieldTwo;

    // the buttons that listen for the user to select an action
    Button addButton, deleteButton, retrieveButton, updateButton;

    // the table that displays the data
    TableLayout dataTable;

    // the class that opens or creates the database and makes sql calls to it
    DBManager db;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // this try catch block returns better error reporting to the log
        try {
            // Android specific calls
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // create the database manager object
            db = new DBManager(this);

            // create references and listeners for the GUI interface
            setupViews();

            // make the buttons clicks perform actions
            addButtonListeners();

            // load the data table
            updateTable();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * creates references and listeners for the GUI interface
     */
    private void setupViews() {
        // THE DATA TABLE
        dataTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.data_table);

        // THE DATA FORM FIELDS
        textFieldOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_field_one);
        textFieldTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_field_two);
        idField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_field);
        updateIDField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.update_id_field);
        updateTextFieldOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.update_text_field_one);
        updateTextFieldTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.update_text_field_two);

        // THE BUTTONS
        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        retrieveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_button);
        updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_button);
    }

    /**
     * adds listeners to each of the buttons and sets them to call relevant methods
     */
    private void addButtonListeners() {
        addButton.setOnClickListener
                (
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                addRow();
                            }
                        }
                );

        deleteButton.setOnClickListener
                (
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                deleteRow();
                            }
                        }
                );

        updateButton.setOnClickListener
                (
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                updateRow();
                            }
                        }
                );

        retrieveButton.setOnClickListener
                (
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                retrieveRow();
                            }
                        }
                );

    }

    /**
     * adds a row to the database based on information contained in the
     * add row fields.
     */
    private void addRow() {
        try {
            // ask the database manager to add a row given the two strings
            db.addRow
                    (
                            textFieldOne.getText().toString(),
                            textFieldTwo.getText().toString()
                    );

            // request the table be updated
            updateTable();

            // remove all user input from the Activity
            emptyFormFields();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Add Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * deletes a row from the database with the id number in the corresponding
     * user entry field
     */
    private void deleteRow() {
        try {
            // ask the database manager to delete the row with the give rowID.
            db.deleteRow(Long.parseLong(idField.getText().toString()));

            // request the table be updated
            updateTable();

            // remove all user input from the Activity
            emptyFormFields();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Delete Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * retrieves a row from the database with the id number in the corresponding
     * user entry field
     */
    private void retrieveRow() {
        try {
            // The ArrayList that holds the row data
            ArrayList<Object> row;
            // ask the database manager to retrieve the row with the given rowID
            row = db.getRowAsArray(Long.parseLong(updateIDField.getText().toString()));

            // update the form fields to hold the retrieved data
            updateTextFieldOne.setText((String) row.get(1));
            updateTextFieldTwo.setText((String) row.get(2));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Retrieve Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * updates a row with the given information in the corresponding user entry
     * fields
     */
    private void updateRow() {
        try {
            // ask the database manager to update the row based on the information
            // found in the corresponding user entry fields
            db.updateRow
                    (
                            Long.parseLong(updateIDField.getText().toString()),
                            updateTextFieldOne.getText().toString(),
                            updateTextFieldTwo.getText().toString()
                    );

            // request the table be updated
            updateTable();

            // remove all user input from the Activity
            emptyFormFields();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Update Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * helper method to empty all the fields in all the forms.
     */
    private void emptyFormFields() {
        textFieldOne.setText("");
        textFieldTwo.setText("");
        idField.setText("");
        updateIDField.setText("");
        updateTextFieldOne.setText("");
        updateTextFieldTwo.setText("");
    }

    /**
     * updates the table from the database.
     */
    private void updateTable() {
        // delete all but the first row.  remember that the count
        // starts at one and the index starts at zero
        while (dataTable.getChildCount() > 1) {
            // while there are at least two rows in the table widget, delete
            // the second row.
            dataTable.removeViewAt(1);
        }

        // collect the current row information from the database and
        // store it in a two dimensional ArrayList
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data = db.getAllRowsAsArrays();

        // iterate the ArrayList, create new rows each time and add them
        // to the table widget.
        for (int position = 0; position < data.size(); position++) {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);

            ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(position);

            TextView idText = new TextView(this);
            idText.setText(row.get(0).toString());
            tableRow.addView(idText);

            TextView textOne = new TextView(this);
            textOne.setText(row.get(1).toString());
            tableRow.addView(textOne);

            TextView textTwo = new TextView(this);
            textTwo.setText(row.get(2).toString());
            tableRow.addView(textTwo);

            dataTable.addView(tableRow);
        }
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#736f6e"
    >

    <!-- ADD A DATA ENTRY FORM -->
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/add_directions"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_field_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="100px"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_field_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="100px"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:text="@string/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="100px"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- DELETE A DATA ENTRY FORM -->
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/delete_directions"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id_field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="100px"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- UPDATE A DATA ENTRY FORM -->
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/update_directions"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/update_id_field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="45px"
            />          
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/retrieve_button"
            android:text="@string/retrieve"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/update_text_field_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="70px"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/update_text_field_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="70px"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/update_button"
            android:text="@string/update"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/tbl_scrollbar"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbarSize="12px"
        >
    <!-- THE DATA TABLE -->
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/data_table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        >
        <TableRow>
            <TextView 
                android:text="@string/th_id"
                android:minWidth="50px"
                />
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/th_text_one"
                android:minWidth="125px"
                />
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/th_text_two"
                android:minWidth="125px"
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MyTask.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#736f6e"
    >

    <!-- ADD A DATA ENTRY FORM -->
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/add_directions"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_field_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="100px"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_field_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="100px"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:text="@string/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="100px"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- DELETE A DATA ENTRY FORM -->
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/delete_directions"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id_field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="100px"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- UPDATE A DATA ENTRY FORM -->
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/update_directions"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/update_id_field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="45px"
            />          
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/retrieve_button"
            android:text="@string/retrieve"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/update_text_field_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="70px"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/update_text_field_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="70px"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/update_button"
            android:text="@string/update"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/tbl_scrollbar"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbarSize="12px"
        >
    <!-- THE DATA TABLE -->
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/data_table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        >
        <TableRow>
            <TextView 
                android:text="@string/th_id"
                android:minWidth="50px"
                />
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/th_text_one"
                android:minWidth="125px"
                />
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/th_text_two"
                android:minWidth="125px"
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```